# making a function where a user inputs a zipcode

Tags: c++, function, zipcode

I'm a new programmer so I'm kind of confused. If I wanted the user to type in a zipcode and want to make sure the user doesn't type more than five numbers how would I go about it. Would I have to create a if statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

void address(int begin, int zipcode) { 
    cout << begin << " Rainbow is my address. My zipcode is " << zipcode << endl;
}
 
int main()
{ 
    cout << "Type in the beginning numbers of your address and the zipcode" << endl; 
    cin >> begin; 
    //cin >> zipcode;
}
```

Comment: Using standard c++ alone you can't easily prevent the user from typing more. You can however check the string after it is typed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they just need to check after the fact.

Comment: Tactical note: When you have a number that's not being used as a number, you aren't doing any math on it, you're probably going to find that you really want a string. In this case, you can easily check if the user gave you more (or less) than 5 characters with a string. With a string you don't have to worry about an input like 00000 showing up in your code as a single 0. You'll find just about everything you need to do with it will come down to interpreting digits separately, and as a string they're already separate. Start with a string and your life will probably be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isValidZipCode(const std::string& zipcode) {
    return zipcode.length() <= 5;
}

void printZipCode(const std::string& zipcode) {
    if (isValidZipCode(zipcode)) {
        std::cout << "Valid zip code: " << zipcode << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid zip code: " << zipcode << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string zipcode;
    std::cout << "Enter a zip code: ";
    std::cin >> zipcode;

    printZipCode(zipcode);

    return 0;
}
```

- The `isValidZipCode` function checks if the length of the zip code string is 5 or less.
- The `printZipCode` function prints whether the zip code is valid or invalid based on the result of `isValidZipCode.
- In the `main` function, the user is prompted to enter a zip code, and then `printZipCode` is called to validate and print the zip code.

Comment: Until a need for a zipcode as a number arises (it likely won't, zipcodes can and do start with zero, string comparisons would work just fine as well), it's better to just read it in and store it as a string.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. I wrote it as `int` cause I saw it being `int` in question. Changed it to `string` in my answer.

Comment: okay makes sense to make the zipcode a string. I appreciate the help.

Comment: In 1963, a US ZIP code is 5 digits (including leading 0s).  In 1983, a ZIP code is 5 digits, hyphen, 4 digits.  Other countries have alphanumeric postal codes.

Comment: Perhaps you could further validate a zip code by requiring that each character in a zip code of length 5 be a digit (for zip codes  in the USA, that is).